# Botao para inserir Registos na Base de Dados

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio

Boas, estou a realizar um projeto para a minha PAP que consiste na criação de uma Base de Dados para uma empresa. No entanto, decidi colocar um botão para adicionar registos e quando clico para adicionar, aparece o seguinte erro: **Falha ao converter o valor do parâmetro de Bitmap para Byte[]**. Que devo eu fazer? Deixo-vos a seguinte imagem que contém o erro e mando por aqui o código:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Utilizador(IDuser, Nome, Localidade, DataDeNascimento, Idade, Email, Login, Senha,Telefone, TelefoneEE, Perfil, Imagem)
                            values (@IDuser, @Nome, @Localidade, @DatadeNascimento, @Idade, @Email, @Login, @Senha, @Telefone, @TelefoneEE, @Perfil, @Imagem", sql);
                     command.Parameters.Add("@IDuser", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = iDuserTextBox.Text;
                     command.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nomeTextBox.Text;
                     command.Parameters.Add("@Localidade", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = localidadeTextBox.Text;
                     command.Parameters.Add("@DataDeNascimento", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dataDeNascimentoDateTimePicker.Value;
                     command.Parameters.Add("@Idade", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idadeTextBox.Text;
                     command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailTextBox.Text;
                     command.Parameters.Add("@Login", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginTextBox.Text;
                     command.Parameters.Add("@Senha", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = senhaTextBox.Text;
                     command.Parameters.Add("@Telefone", SqlDbType.Char).Value = telefoneTextBox.Text;
                     command.Parameters.Add("@TelefoneEE", SqlDbType.Char).Value = telefoneEETextBox.Text;
                     command.Parameters.Add("@Imagem", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imagemPictureBox.Image;
                     command.Parameters.Add("@Perfil", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = perfilTextBox.Text;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tente converter manualmente a imagem para byte antes de mandar pro banco

```cs
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
imagem = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
```

Comment: Boas, meto esse código antes do private void btnAdicionar_Click? Ou dentro do mesmo?

Comment: Pode ser dentro mesmo, depende de como vc ta estruturando seu projeto

Comment: Boas, fiz o que sugeriu mas deu erro em ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
**imagem** = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(**img**, typeof(byte[]));

em vez de imagem meti ImagemPicturebox mas no img não sei o que alterar

Comment: coloca a imagem que vc quer converter no lugar de `img`, em `imagem` é o nome da váriável que você vai armazenar, aí você vai mandar pro banco a variável `imagem`

Comment: Deixei assim o código: ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            imagem = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(imagemPictureBox, typeof(byte[]));
No entanto continua a dar erro em imagem...